# How to change colour of -webkit-appearance -moz-window-button-close

Tags: html, css, webkit, webkit-appearance

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqXGC.png)

How do you change colour of -webkit-appearance -moz-window-button-close? As you can see in the image at the moment it's blue and I want to be able to change the colour to the brown that the rest of the textbox uses.

I've set the background-color, color and hyperlink styles but none of it affected the X icon in the right of the text box.

I've searched around a lot but I haven't found a solution, maybe I'm just not using the right keywords.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: can you share the link of the page you took the screenshot from? normally font awesome colours can just be overridden with the `color` property in CSS. if it didn't work on the `h1` tag, try styling it based on the `.fa` or `.fa-search` classes (or both) within the `h1` for better specificity

Comment: The screenshot is way too large. Can you crop it to only include the important part (preferably [with a frame](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2021/03/02/krita-on-linux-as-the-equivalent-to-windows-paint/#Create_a_frame))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it took me a long time to figure this out. Essentially there is only a single resource that I found which would allow this to work. However, the author states that fewer and fewer browsers are supporting it.

**Lesson to be learned** - Don't bother using WebKit for trying to add icons inside. Just build it up yourself with HTML, CSS, and [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) (or alternatives).

I took a different approach which, although involves jQuery, seems to work fine. I built up a span to give the same appearance, used jQuery to control the visibility and display properties, font-awesome for the search icon and CSS gave the initial display and visibility settings:

```js
function searchIconClicked() {
  if ($("#searchBorderbox").css('display') == "none") {
    $("#searchIcon").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#searchBorderbox").css("display", "inline");
    $('#searchBorderbox').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#searchBorderbox').animate({
      "width": 440
    });
    $('#searchBorderbox').promise().done(function() {
      $('#clearSearchTextboxIcon').css('display', 'inline');
      $("#searchIcon").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
  }
}

function clearSearchTextbox() {
  $("#searchTextbox").val('');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchIcon").on('click', searchIconClicked)
  $("#clearSearchTextboxIcon").on('click', clearSearchTextbox)

  $('#searchTextbox').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
      $('#clearSearchTextboxIcon').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
      $('#clearSearchTextboxIcon').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #023930;
}

#quoteBox {
  margin-top: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 45%;
}

#quoteBoxText {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.brownBorder {
  color: #855F1C !important;
}

.searchSpanBox {
  display: none;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #855F1C !important;
  background-color: #023930;
  border-spacing: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchTextbox {
  background-color: #023930;
  width: 0%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 380px;
  border: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
}

#clearSearchTextboxIcon {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main col-xs-12" id="quoteBox">
    <div id="quoteBoxText">
      <h1><span id="searchBorderbox" class="brownBorder searchSpanBox"><input type="search" id="searchTextbox" class="searchTextbox"><a id="clearSearchTextboxIcon">&#10006;</a></span> <i id="searchIcon" class="fa fa-search fa-lg brownBorder" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code needs tidying up a bit but that works as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try: Add`-webkit-appearance: none;` to `input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button` and style using an image. Please refer to CodePen for an example - [Codepen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wJ4r.png)